# Compare registry tree with reg-file

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, registry

i would like to compare a path in the registry including the whole subtree with a premade .reg file and only if it matches (all values are the same), i would execute some action.

are there some tools for this or is there a .net samplecode to do something?

will i have to recursively check through the whole tree and compare value by value or can i use some function that does that?

all i found so far, is:

```
RegistryKey rootKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\services\\TwTouch");
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [REGDIFF](http://p-nand-q.com/download/regdiff.html):

> regdiff is a small command line tool to compare two registry files,
>   export the registry, merge .REG files and much more.
>
> How to compare a registry key with a given .REG file
>
> You can use regdiff.exe to compare any registry key with a given .REG
>   file:

```
regdiff.exe HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE hklm_software.reg
```

Comment: thanks, that tool seems perfect, only problem is, i cant use .net 4.5. but at least it is open source!